# supress console window appear on periodical schedule program runnig tests

Tags: cmd.exe, script, scheduled-tasks

Have windows console program which should be alwys running on VISIBLE CMD WINDOW (Session ID 1). The program checking and displaying network data, but if network resource is not (temporarily) available, it terminate (as a program feature).

Have scheduled task which periodically start script which check if such binary run, and start one if not.

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "imagename eq ttg.exe" | findstr "ttg.exe" >NUL
if errorlevel 1 start "" "C:\utils\ttg.exe" par1 par2
```

It work as expected, but it display (blink) additional cmd windows every 5 minutes (by schedule). Task option "Run only when user is loggend on" is choosed. When choose "Run whether user is loggen or not", program is started invisibly with SessionID 0.

How could I start program itself visibly, but suppress peridical cmd windows appearance?

Comment: The Task Scheduler is problematic. I would suggest to put the batch file in the Startup group at  `C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Comment: I would create scheduled task to start such program, with flags "only of user is logged on" and "if program is running, do not launch again"